# How to call a Struts2 action from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, java, struts2

First of all, I don't know if is possible or not, so I read a lot of posts before asking, how can I call Struts2 action from a JavaScript function?

**Examples (Forms):**

http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/example-to-call-struts2-action-from-java-script
[how to call method in action class in javascript using struts2 framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203415/how-to-call-method-in-action-class-in-javascript-using-struts2-framework])
[how to redirect to struts action from java script in struts 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432092/how-to-redirect-to-struts-action-from-java-script-in-struts-2)
[How to call a method in Struts2 Action Class method with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778527/how-to-call-a-method-in-struts2-action-class-method-with-javascript)
https://coderanch.com/t/533202/framework/Calling-Action-Class-javaScript-Struts
https://coderanch.com/t/530746/framework/call-method-action-class-Struts
https://coderanch.com/t/551141/framework/call-Struts-action-javascript-function

Thanks for your help.

I put the Struts.xml file where you can see the Struts2 actions and the javascriptFunctions.js that contains de borrarPerfil() where as you can see I need to call Struts2 action

**Struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="registrar" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="registrar" class="registrar.action.Registrar"
        method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/estructura/finRegistro.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="dispatcher">/estructura/registro.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="tiles" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    <action name="*Menu" method="{1}" class="tiles.action.MenuAction">
        <result name="inicio" type="tiles">inicio</result>
        <result name="quienes" type="tiles">quienes</result>
        <result name="servicios" type="tiles">servicios</result>
        <result name="donde" type="tiles">donde</result>
        <result name="contacto" type="tiles">contacto</result>
    </action>

    <action name="*Usuario" method="{1}" class="tiles.action.UsuarioAction">
        <result name="perfil" type="tiles">perfil</result>
        <result name="agenda" type="tiles">agenda</result>
        <result name="servicios" type="tiles">mservicios</result>
        <result name="consulta" type="tiles">consulta</result>
        <result name="ayuda" type="tiles">ayuda</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="contacto" extends="tiles">
    <action name="validar" class="validar.action.Validar" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">finContacto</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">contacto</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="login" extends="tiles">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="login.interceptor.LoginInterceptor">
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <!-- login action -->
    <action name="login" class="login.action.Login">
        <result name="input" type="tiles">inicio</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">usuarioLayout</result>
    </action>

    <!-- logout action -->
    <action name="logout" class="login.action.Login" method="logout">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">inicio</result>
    </action>

</package>

<package name="modificar" extends="tiles">
    <action name="modificar" class="modificar.action.Modificar" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">finModificar</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">menuLayout</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="borrar" extends="titles">
    <action name="borrar" class="borrar.action.Borrar">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">inicio"</result>    
    </action>
</package>
```

javascriptFunctions.js

```
function borrarPerfil() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this profile?")){
        alert("deleted");
       //CALL STRUTS2 ACTION borrar 

    } else {
        alert("no paso nada");
     //CALL STRUTS2 ACTION logout   
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking Struts2 reacts on http calls that has a mapping to the url. It could expose some api that you can access with any http client.

Comment: You can get a form in js function, and then submit it to an action. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Same way as you call any back-end function from JavaScript. It's not clear what specific issue you think you have.

Comment: Hello, thanks for yours quickly answer but I don't need to use a form. Today when I have time will put the code to can show what I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve how call from javascript function. It should be like this:

javascriptFunctions.js

```
function borrarPerfil() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this profile?")){
        alert("deleted");
        window.location = "/Barcelona_Business_World_v2/borrar";
    } else {
        alert("no paso nada");
        window.location = "/Barcelona_Business_World_v2/logout";
    }   
}
```

I was wrong because I used the next to call the strut2 action:

```
window.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout";
```

I read that it's the correct way to do but I don't know why in my function fail. I will read more about contextPath.

Thanks.